# select more ranges in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, range

How do I SELECT  multiple ranges in MySQL taking in consideration the following scenario: let say I want to get back from my product table products where

price 0 - 300 and price 600-1000 price 1200-1600

I was trying the following

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE price > 0 
  AND price <= 300 
  AND price >= 600 
  AND price <= 1000
```

but doesn't return any rows

Comment: Do you want the results to be grouped? Does it have to be one query? If yes - I think you can not achieve this in one query.

Comment: Well your telling it that it must be between the first two and the second two at the same time. That's not possible, you need to use an `OR` for this statement. So it should be something like `price between price OR price between price`

Comment: thank you for the feedback I'm going to try OR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a number is between `0` and `300` it can't **also** be between `600` and `1000`. Are you looking for `OR`? Perhaps with [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) just to make things easier?

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE
    price BETWEEN 0 AND 300
    OR
    price BETWEEN 600 AND 1000
    OR
    price BETWEEN 1200 AND 1600
```

Comment: So you could also state SELECT * FROM product WHERE price BETWEEN 0 AND 1000 - would not make any difference in the result.

Comment: @osterhase Of course it would? What about 301-599 and 1001-1199?

Comment: 0 will be included in this statement but the original query excluded 0: `price > 0`

Comment: @Koryu Yet OP's question was *price 0 - 300 and price 600-1000 price 1200-1600*, and he includes 600 in his query as "greater than *or equal to*", so it's difficult to know if 1-300 is what OP actually wants. If so, it'd be super simple to change the number in the query. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE 
(price > 0 AND price <= 300 )
OR
(price > 600 AND price <= 1000)
OR
(price > 1200 AND price <= 1600 )
```

you can also use between

```
price BETWEEN 0 AND 300
or
price between ...
```

consider that between `price BETWEEN 0 AND 300` will include 0 
it will be parsed into `price >= 0 AND price <= 300`

Answer (score 0):

use 'or' condition instead of 'and'

Comment: As you are kinda correct, try to show some code and explain why it should be used. Reading this someone may think to change all `AND` to `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

You certanly need something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE
    (price > 0 AND price <= 300) OR
    (price > 600 AND price <= 1000) OR
    (price > 1200 AND price <= 1600)
```